# Class 'App\Jobs\DateTime' not found when moving my code to App\Jobs;

Tags: php, laravel

I have a piece of code that was working well in a controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DateTime;
use DateTimeZone;

class MissingDataController extends Controller
{

    public function scan(Request $request)
    {

    $transitions = MissingData::getTransitionArray($tz, new DateTime('2018-01-01'), new 
    DateTime('NOW'));
    }
}
```

Now, I moved this code into a Job, now I have:

```
class MissingDataController extends Controller
{

    public function scan(Request $request)
    {
        ScanMissingData::dispatch();
    }
}
```

with job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Measure;
use App\MissingData;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class ScanMissingData implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // set the params pliz
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $tz = new DateTimeZone(config('app.timezone'));
        $transitions = MissingData::getTransitionArray($tz, new \DateTime('2018-01-01'), new \DateTime('NOW'));
    }
}
```

Now, I get in my logs:

```
[2020-08-27 16:58:48] local.ERROR: Class 'App\Jobs\DateTime' not found
```

I tried to use it with a backslash, or without ( adding `use DateTime;` as import) but it doesn't work.

What should I do ?

EDIT:

Added the full log:

```
[2020-08-27 17:25:58] local.ERROR: Class 'App\Jobs\DateTime' not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class 'App\\Jobs\\DateTime' not found at /home/julien/Code/acc/app/Jobs/ScanMissingData.php:42)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: App\\Jobs\\ScanMissingData->handle()
#1 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): call_user_func_array()
#2 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#3 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(95): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#4 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(39): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#5 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(596): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#6 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#7 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}()
#8 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#9 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#10 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(83): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchNow()
#11 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->Illuminate\\Queue\\{closure}()
#12 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#13 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(85): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#14 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(59): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware()
#15 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(98): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->call()
#16 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(356): Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\Job->fire()
#17 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(306): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process()
#18 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(132): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob()
#19 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(112): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon()
#20 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(96): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker()
#21 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/Console/WorkCommand.php(46): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#22 [internal function]: Laravel\\Horizon\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#23 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): call_user_func_array()
#24 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#25 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(95): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#26 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(39): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#27 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(596): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#28 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(134): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#29 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(258): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute()
#30 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()
#31 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(911): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run()
#32 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(264): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
#33 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(140): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#34 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
#35 /home/julien/Code/acc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run()
#36 /home/julien/Code/acc/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#37 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Are you sure `use DateTime` in your Job class doesn't work? And remove prefix from `new DateTime(...`

Comment: Yep, I double checked it

Comment: can you once run ``composer update`` in your project and try again.

Comment: I ran composer update, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you try without a slash and also without `use DateTime`? Alternatively, if you're using Laravel, why not use `Carbon`? It's built it :) https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ for reference

Comment: Composer will not solve the problem, DateTime and DateTimeZone are PHP core functions, these classes do not need autoload. His problem is related to the class namespace.
Once it has declared the namespace, all calls to native PHP classes must be made with \ before (Or be imported with use also using \ before)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this lines:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DateTime;
use DateTimeZone;
```

as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \DateTime;
use \DateTimeZone;
```

Since these functions are from the php core, they use the root namespace, and when you define a namespace for your class, all calls to new instances within it are relative to the defined namespace, unless you use the initial " \ "

**Edit:**
In ScanMissingData class change this piece of code:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $tz = new DateTimeZone(config('app.timezone'));
        $transitions = MissingData::getTransitionArray($tz, new \DateTime('2018-01-01'), new \DateTime('NOW'));
    }
```

to:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $tz = new \DateTimeZone(config('app.timezone'));
        $transitions = MissingData::getTransitionArray($tz, new \DateTime('2018-01-01'), new \DateTime('NOW'));
    }
```

Comment: On ScanMissingData you've never imported DateTimezone, try to instante all non imported DateTime and DateTime with a "\". By the way, where (file and line) is the error triggered?

Comment: I added the full log at the end of my question. the error is on         `$tz = new DateTimeZone(config('app.timezone'));` which is the first occurence of `DateTimeZone`

Comment: OK, try to change DateTimeZone to \DateTimeZone

Comment: I debug a bit, and adding a slash before DateTimeZone is working. But the next line, same example with DateTime won't work... I don't understand

Comment: I separated all the call to DateTime to separates lines, so I can know which one is failing, it is still the first one

Comment: same exception trace?

Comment: I think I will use Carbon! At this level, it will be quicker I guess

Comment: But Carbon is only a abstraction to DateTime... hehe
See the error line, and check if all calls to DateTime and DateTimeZone are with a \ .

Comment: I think this is not a problem with DateTime, somehow, there is a lot of weird thing happening when I move lines of code to debug, I think I have some cache issues, or something like that.

Comment: It is really possible that it is something related to caching if you are running your code on an online server, but in the local environment it is unlikely.
Check the uppercase and lowercase letters as well.
However, if you are still viewing your namespace together with the DateTime or DateTimeZone class, there may still be some place in your code that needs to be revised.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Validate the namespace in your class files

2 - You must run `composer dump-autoload`